# First build fails with WiX and NuGet

Tags: wix, nuget

My Visual Studio 2017 solution uses WiX v3.11.1 to produce an installer. WiX has been installed using the NuGet package manager (with disableSourceControlIntegration set to true in the NuGet configuration).

If I delete the solution from my PC and get the solution from VSTS, it downloads all of the solution except the contents of the package folder (where WiX should reside). If I build the project, the WiX project fails with the following message:

> The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to
>   build this project. To download the WiX Toolset.

Even though the build failed, the package folder now contains "WiX.3.11.1". If I restart Visual Studio, the project builds fine.

How can I ensure that the project builds first time without having to restart Visual Studio? It seems that when WiX starts the build, it doesn't detect NuGet has just downloaded the "WiX.3.11.1" package.